# Widehat duplication problem

Tags: equations

I get a problem where every part of the equation gets duplicated when using `\widehat`.

[image]

I want:
[image]

I use the following code:

```
    \begin{equation}
    \widehat{R_i_t} = \widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta_i} \times R_m_t \tag{2}
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: clearly there is a mistake in a definition in code you have not shown, please fix your example so it is a complete small document that makes the ouput shown, so people can debug it.

Comment: `{R_i_t}` will give a double subscript error that should be `R_{it}`  unrelated to widehat, never ignore error messages!

Comment: You keep asking questions without ever giving some complete code reproducing your issues. Sorry to be blunt, but you're not going to get much help in this way. Please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/82917. Help us help you!

Comment: When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.